# Static IPv6 not retained despite configuration

Tags: debian, ipv6

I want one of my machine to get a static IPv6, which should be allowed by my ISP.

When I configure the machine for a static ip, it works well for a few days/months, then I get assigned a different IP.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about IPv6.

I configured my the OS (Rasbian) this way:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet6 static
address 2a01:e35:2e35:e860:ba27:ebff:fe15:81e4;
netmask 64
gateway 2a01:e35:2e35:e860::1
```

Running ifconfig gives that output

```
{pi@raspberrypi[pi]}sudo ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:15:81:e4
          inet addr:192.168.0.42  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a01:e35:2e35:e860:ba27:ebff:fe15:81e4/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe15:81e4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2640 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2130 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:330543 (322.7 KiB)  TX bytes:343149 (335.1 KiB)
```

Note that I do have (at least outbound) IPv6 connectivity

How to keep the same IPv6 all the time instead of getting assigned a slightly different one after some time ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @kasperd I clarified a bit.